# Событие изменения поля input

Tags: события, javascript

есть каледарь на js.

```
<input id="date" type="text" name="dat1" class="date" maxlength=50 size=25%  oninput ="getElementById('newFormAdv').submit()"/>
```

при выборе даты меняется поле с датой. как отследить это? пробовал onchange, oninput, onselect - не оно, может меняется чисто визуально, но какое событие это может быть?

Comment: а вы для выбора даты используете библиотеку? Обычно у таких библ. есть в опциях метод onchange:function(e,ui){arert(ui.selectedYear, ui.selectedMonth, ui.selectedDay);}

Comment: пожалуйста, развива́йте свою тему

Comment: использую 

          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
но метода onchange не нашел

Comment: @anunak, у jquery есть UI datepicker, вот здесь всё написано http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/  прочтите там про метод onchange

Comment: @anunak, bootstrap-datepicker там похоже метод getDate попробуйте так: 

    getDate:function(d){alert(JSON.stringify(d));} посмотрите что там

Comment: вы про это?

    $(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
  }
});

Comment: @anunak, да, но там есть еще onchange, ну и так пойдет думаю.

Comment: нашел такое http://jsbin.com/upubix/208